# carousel slider that has a video background and product tags covering the video (almost there)

Tags: javascript, video, tags, slider, interactive

Hi all thx for reading my post i am working on a full with carousel slider that has a video background and product tags covering the video.

So basicly this is what i am trying to make:

slide slides in view the video in the background starts playing 2 to 3 sec max video stops playing then the tags come in view over the video.

Now you can click on the tags and get a nice div next to the tag with info about the product.

Then if the slide translates automaticly or is clickt it should rewind the video to 0 and replay again from the begining its importend it dosent reload the video becouse it wil consume MB from the user.

please check what i have so far i have added images so you can see what i meen with the product tags.

Tyvm in advace

what i have at the moment T-T :http://jsfiddle.net/rsyedv2j/

```
html test
```

[Image example of what i meen about the tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0v7lT.jpg)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Firstly tyvm for looking at my post, the quastion is how can i make the video play from the beginning every time the slide its on is active so if i click next and back it wil have to start from the start and also if its slides by it self it has to start by the beginning again. with somthing like this: `video.currentTime = 0; // Restart` and target it with somthing like this `$('#myCarousel').bind('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    console.log('slide event!');

});

$('#myCarousel').bind('slid', function (e) {
    console.log("slid event!");
});` but i cant get it to work T-T